# Find $x$ which satisfies the following equation

Tags: trigonometry, logarithms

Find $x$ such that

$\dfrac{6(3x^2-27)8x^2}{4(9-3x)(x^2+3x)} = \dfrac{\tan(x+4)}{\ln(x+\frac{1}{4})}$

I've managed to reduce the left hand side so that

$-12x= \dfrac{\tan(x+4)}{\ln(x+\frac{1}{4})}= \dfrac{\tan(x+4)}{\ln(\frac{4x+1}{4})} = \dfrac{\tan(x+4)}{\ln(4x+1)-\ln(4)}$

But I'm unsure on how to deal with both the $\tan(x+4)$ and $\ln(4x+1)$. I've tried using the maclaurin series expansion for $\tan(\alpha)$ and $\ln(1+\beta)$, with $\alpha=x+4$ and $\beta=4x$ but this just gives an over complicated fraction which I cannot reduce to get a solution for $x$.

Comment: i would say that only a numerical method will help here

Comment: First of all notice that:

$$\dfrac{6(3x^2-27)8x^2}{4(9-3x)(x^2+3x)}=-12x$$

For $x\ne -3,x\ne 0,x\ne 3$

Comment: This is a [transcendental equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_equation) with an infinity of solutions, each on an interval of the form $\bigg(\big(2k-1\big)\dfrac\pi2,~\big(2k+1\big)\dfrac\pi2\bigg)$.